# Minimum hardware requirements for a Hornet + WASP node

Tags: smart-contract, hornet

```
Hornet minimum hardware specs:
4 cores or 4 vCPU.
8 GB RAM.
SSD storage.
```

What percentage of the hardware spec is often used? I'm wondering by how much I should increase the VPS cores & RAM for a Hornet + WASP node